# Testing basic http authenticaation with digest using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, curl, basic-authentication

How can we test authentication with digest as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html#label-Simple+Digest+example) using curl?

I am able to test [Simple Basic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html#label-Simple+Basic+example) example by setting `Authorization` header to `Basic {SECRET}` where `SECRET` is `Base64::encode64("username:password")` as explained [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic#197-Testing-protected-controllers)

I tried sending `Authentication` header with same value but getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'unpack' for nil:NilClass)` on line having call `authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest`

Would anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I am able to fix the problem. Here is how I used curl to test http basic authentication with digest

```
curl --data {"red":"00"} --digest -u "username:password" "http://localhost:3000/api/statistics"
```